# How to resize the QMenuBar in PyQt4 for a 4K display

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I need to write an application in Python with a User Interface. I decided to go for PyQt4 to make the GUI. It is included in the Anaconda distribution of Python.

To make a GUI running smoothly on a 4K display is not trivial. Most components are way too small by default. Some components - like buttons - are easy to resize:

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit", self)
btn.resize(100,100)
```

But how do I resize other components, like the QMenuBar? Can I make the QMenu buttons (Like "File", "Edit", ..) that populate the QMenuBar larger? Can I make the WindowTitle in the top left corner also larger?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the font and font-size of individual widgets.

```
font = self.menuBar().font()
font.setPointSize(20)
self.menuBar().setFont(font)
```

But typically something like this would be handled by your OS/window manager.  I'm assuming all your other applications have text that looks just as small?  For high-res displays, most popular OS's have scaling features to emulate the size of a lower resolution monitor.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Brendan Abel.
Your answer is very helpful!

Comment: I just tried it out, and it works pretty fine. Only the Window title is stuck at the small font size. How would you enlarge the window title size with PyQt4?
Kind greetings,

Comment: Can't change it with Qt.  That's drawn by your OS window manager.

Comment: Oh. Any idea how to reach the "OS window manager" in python? Thank you for all the help. I really appreciate this.

Comment: Depends on the OS you're using.  But generally, you wouldn't change this on an application by application basis.  You'd change the OS setting for all windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answers really helped me 